# Upload image with datauri as source empty on ajax post call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, data-uri

Hi Guys i cropped my image using jcrop and i have the data_uri for the cropped imaged i have collated them all into an array but it seems the array could not be passed when i make my ajax request as the array is empty in the php. here's my code below

JS

```
var cropped_images = {/**array of data_uris **/};
console.log(cropped_images); // still have my array intact
    $.post(url,cropped_images,function(data){
        console.log(data) //empty
    }
)
```

PHP

```
public function url_from_ajax()
{
   this->view = false;
   return json_encode($this->input->post()) //i'm using codeigniter so the post format is valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to stringify your array:

```
var cropped_images = {/**array of data_uris **/};
var jsonImages = JSON.stringify(cropped_images);
console.log(cropped_images); // still have my array intact
console.log(jsonImages); // still have my array intact
    $.post(url,jsonImages,function(data){
        console.log(data) //empty
    }
)
```

Comment: no difference i think the problem is that the data_uri are too long

Comment: That's unlikely with a POST request. Is the POST really empty? Can you add a var_dump or print_r at the first line of your `url_from_ajax` method?

Comment: same thing i've already tried that before even posting. that's why i logged before and after. it seems the data is not passed along with the post request .because it is too long

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are posting?

Comment: it is the canvas.toDataURL() of an image and it's way longer than 540 letters. it is the uri gotten after drawing image on canvas.

Comment: Odd.. Maybe you can check your max_post_size ?